# Convert nested li to group array

Tags: jquery

This is the closest I've got...

```js
var myArray = $(".req").map(function() {
    return $(".ans > li").text();
}).get();
console.log(myArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="req">apple
    <ul class="ans">
      <li>apple1</li>
      <li>apple2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="req">banana
    <ul class="ans">
      <li>banana1</li>
      <li>banana2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The outcome I need:

```
  [
  apple = ["apple1", "apple2"],
  banana = ["banana1", "banana2"]
  ]
```

I'm not a coder and can only edit existing codes, been doing some trial and error but still no success... thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize an empty array object and populate it like this:

```js
var answer = {};
$.each($("li.req"), function() {
    var type = $(this).text().split("\n")[0];
    answer[type] = $(this).find("li").map(function() {
        return $(this).text()
    }).get()
});
console.log(answer)
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="req">apple
    <ul class="ans">
      <li>apple1</li>
      <li>apple2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="req">banana
    <ul class="ans">
      <li>banana1</li>
      <li>banana2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```